# MutationObserver - Listening for mutations to an element's style property (e.g display)

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

For reference: [MutationObserver Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

I'm currently trying to observe mutations to the DOM, specifically for elements whose `overflow` style has changed. As far as I can tell, I can listen for changes to an element's 'style' attribute using `attributeFilter: ['style']` but not to properties within 'style' (e.g 'overflow' or 'display'). Am I correct in saying this? If so, is there an efficient solution to detect changes to an element's style property?

Comment: You're right. And this is the most efficient way is to observe an element. However in new browsers IntersectionObserver may be a better solution depending on the ultimate goal.